# What color corrections are being used here?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, color-correction

Trying this one more time.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OfNz.jpg

I like the moody tones and the softness. It seems curves are being used in some way but I'm not sure how. More examples: http://ilovewildfox.com/lonely-dot-seattle/.

I'm not really sure how else to describe it except that I like the tones and the warmth. The photos are almost cinematic, with deep black and soft beige, almost? I tried messing around with beige overlays but still couldn't get it quite right.

I'm doing the best I can trying to explain myself. If you let me know how a better way, I'll take your suggestions and revise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a raised black level and a little yellow cast.  Here is the original:

[image]

Using the plastic bottle a a white referece and then expanding the dynamic range to the fullest, we get:

[image]

That seems to have the effect you talk about removed.  The white level as measured from the bottle was 1.000, .931, .886, so definitely yellowish as was apparent just by looking at the original.

The shadow detail was pretty poor to begin with, and has been made worse by fixing the black level.  Some non-linear brightening can help with that:

[image]

The original question has been answered. Now we're getting into what we think the picture should look like, so I'll stop here.

Comment: So how do you think the yellow cast was achieved? Color balance, overlay...? Or is that too hard to determine?

Comment: @user: Now you're getting into the software and user interface specifics.  Ultimately the math for the same result is the same.  You'd probably think of it in terms of a specific white balance point, but of course there are other ways.